# Medicare Plan B penalty for late enrolment

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, health

I have dual citizenship for the UK and US and have full insurance coverage with the NHS in the UK and also have Medicare plan A.  I have pensions in both countries.  I will be moving back to the US but told I must pay a late enrolment for Plan B.

Is this correct and any suggestions if I need to appeal?

Comment: Medicare's Part B Special Enrollment Period instructions seem designed for US residents as it only mentions coverage by employer or spouse's employer. You'll probably want to contact your Social Security office and ask them if NHS coverage qualifies you for the special enrollment period.

Answer (score 1):

See [Signing up for Parts A & B outside the U.S.](https://www.medicare.gov/information-for-my-situation/signing-up-for-parts-a-b-outside-the-us)

It seems to depend on whether you were eligible for Social Security benefits while living in the UK. If you were not, you may have a three month window to file during a special enrollment period without penalty.

I suggest contacting your local Social Security office to get advice on this as soon as possible.